# I have a python script running inside a container of kubernetes pod.How do i stop the script which runs along with the starting of the pod?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, kubernetes, python-multithreading

I am running two threads inside the container of the Kubernetes pod one thread pushes some data to db and other thread (flask app) shows the data from database. So as soon as the pod starts up main.py(starts both the threads mentioned above) will be called.

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY app/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app .

CMD ["python3","./main.py"]
```

I have two questions:

1. Is logs the only way to see the output of the running script? Can't we see its output continuously as it runs on the terminal?
2. Also, I m not able to run the same main.py file by going into the container. It throws below error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 920, in run
  run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1008, in run_simple
  inner()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 948, in inner
  srv = make_server(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 780, in make_server
  return ThreadedWSGIServer(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 686, in __init__
  super().__init__(server_address, handler) # type: ignore
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
  self.server_bind()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
  socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
  self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use (edited)
```

How do I stop the `main.py` script which starts along with the pod and be able to run the main.py from the container itself directly?

Thank you.

Comment: Stopping the `main.py` from `CMD` basically stops the main process of the container thus will kill the container & pod. Maybe you want to leave that process alone but instead run another instance of `main.py` with a different port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says all:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use (edited)
```

It looks like your python script tries to open the same port twice. You cannot do that. Check your code and fix it.

Now answering your other question:

> Is logs the only way to see the output of the running script? Can't we see its output continuously as it runs on the terminal?

Running `kubectl logs -f` will follow the logs, which should let you see the output continuously as it runs in terminal.

Comment: As soon as the pod starts it starts the container then main.py will be called where I got some error due to api connection and the script stopped. Now when I tried to go into the container and run python3 main.py I got the above error. 
How do I stop the main.py which started along with the pod creation?
I am not accessing the same port twice inside the code.It works perfectly in docker.

Comment: Is there any way to kill the main.py script which started with the pod and run python3 main.py from the container without killing the pod?

Comment: no, you can't swap the processes. And you are indeed accessing the same port twice inside the container then you run python3 main.py. One main.py process is already running. When you start the second process it will result in error because it tries to bind to the port that is already reserved by the other process.